# how to find No.of Sockets in solaris physical and solaris servers in Zone . what is the difference

Tags: solaris

I looking for CPU details from solaris 10/9/8/7/6 .also I want to get cpu info for solaris zone servers.No.of Sockets,No.of Cores,No.of Cores per Socket,No.of Logical Processors(or vCPUs)
Regards,
shijo

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`psrinfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5166/psrinfo-1m.html#scrolltoc) command.

Comment: psrinfo not working on some of the solaris versions. some of the old ver I think.